# Let AutoMapper throw error for getter-only properties

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Is there a way I can make AutoMapper throw an error when calling `AssertConfigurationIsValid` when the target type contains a readonly (or getter only if you will) property that is settable in the source? It is silently ignored by default and AutoMapper does not seem to contain configuration to do it differently.

```
class Program
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Hello { get; set; }
        public string World { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public int Hello { get; set; }
        public string World { get; } // Should throw error
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>());
        Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1837

Comment: Thanks @RomanMarusyk - That was two years ago. I am hoping someone has tackled this by now.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html#custom-validations